# Unity - Mathf.Lerp() didn't work as expected?

Tags: unity, rotation, lerp

I want to rotate an object 360 degrees so this is what I did:
`xRotation = Mathf.Lerp(0, 360, Time.fixedDeltaTime * lerpTime)`

and then I used Quaternion.Lerp() to rotate the Object so:

```
targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(initialRotation.x + xRotation, initialRotation.y, initialRotation.z);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, Time.fixedDeltaTime * lerpTime);
```

But it didn't work as expected, the xRotation didn't go from 0 to 360, it just changed from 0 to 9 (instantly), and that's it, it never changed.

This is my full code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class QuaternionExpirement : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    [SerializeField] [Range(5, 10)] float lerpTime;
    Vector3 initialRotation;
    bool mousePress, readyToRotate;
    float xRotation;


    private void Awake()
    {
        initialRotation = Vector3.zero;
        mousePress = false;
        readyToRotate = false;
        xRotation = 0;
    }


    private void Update()
    {
        mousePress = Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0);
    }

    
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (mousePress)
        {
            initialRotation = transform.eulerAngles;
            readyToRotate = true;
        }


        if (readyToRotate)
        {
            xRotation = Mathf.Lerp(0, 360, Time.fixedDeltaTime * lerpTime);
            Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(initialRotation.x + xRotation, initialRotation.y, initialRotation.z);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, Time.fixedDeltaTime * lerpTime);
            
            if (xRotation >= 360)
            {
                readyToRotate = false;
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have not really understood what the functions you use actually do.
The `Time.fixedDeltaTime`, as per the documentation, returns the time between each physics update in seconds. This is a **fixed** value (e.g. for 50 physics updates per second this will be 0.02). Now, `lerpTime` is **also** a fixed value in your case from my understanding. This means that in **every** `FixedUpdate()` call, the `Mathf.Lerp` function will return **the same** value (`360 * 0.02 * lerpTime`), in your case 9, which means that `Time.fixedDeltaTime * lerpTime = 0.025`.

In order to fix the problem the `Time.fixedDeltaTime * lerpTime` must not be a constant value but must be updated each frame in order to start from 0.025 and eventually reach 1 after 40 frames.

```
float previousInterpolation = 0f; // member variable
FixedUpdate() {
  previousInterpolation = Time.fixedDeltaTime * lerpTime + previousInterpolation;
  xRotation = Mathf.Lerp(0, 360, previousInterpolation);
}
```

Comment: You want to divide by lerpTime and not multiply by it. As I read the question, the rotation should happen over the the duration of lerpTime and not as a speed.